# How to cutomize the gradio app interface and tigger a function based on output of first interface?

Tags: python, huggingface, gradio

Here is the sample code. I want to trigger function2 based on the output of function one.
I did it by two interface but and launch them together but I am not looking for extra interface.

**I Tried**

```
# Define your functions
def function1(input1):
    # Your code here
    return 'hello'

def function2(create_ticket):
    # Your code here
    return 'Your ticket has been created '

interface1 = gr.Interface(fn=listen_audio, inputs=gr.Audio(sources="microphone", type="filepath"),outputs="text")

interface2 = gr.Interface(fn=function2, inputs=["checkbox"], outputs="text")

lst = [x for x in dir(interface1) if '__' not in x]
# Combine them using Blocks
with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    with gr.Row():
        with gr.Column():
            interface1.render()
        with gr.Column():
            # interface2.render()
            interface2.render()
demo.launch()
```

**Expecting ..**

```
import gradio as gr

def listen_audio(input1):
    return 'problem'

def function2(output_of_listen_audio_function):
    return 'Ticket has been created'
demo = gr.Interface(fn=listen_audio, inputs=gr.Audio(sources="microphone", type="filepath"), outputs="text", 
                    flagging_options=["Create Ticket"],
                    # allow_flagging = "never"
                    )
demo.launch()
```

[image: app frontend below]

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired functionality of triggering function2 based on the output of function1 within a single Gradio interface, you can use the live option in Gradio. The live option allows you to update the state of the interface based on the output of a previous component.

```
import gradio as gr

# Define your functions
def listen_audio(input1):
    # Your code here
    return 'hello'

def create_ticket(output_of_listen_audio_function):
    # Your code here
    return 'Your ticket has been created '

# Create the Gradio interface
demo = gr.Interface(fn=listen_audio, 
                    inputs=gr.Audio(sources="microphone", type="filepath"), 
                    outputs="text",
                    live=True)  # Set live to True to enable dynamic updates

# Add a component for creating a ticket
demo.add_component(component=create_ticket, 
                   inputs=["checkbox"], 
                   outputs="text",
                   live=True,  # Set live to True for dynamic updates
                   live_inputs=[0])  # Specify the index of the input to be updated dynamically

# Launch the Gradio interface
demo.launch()
```

In this example, I've set live=True for both components. The live_inputs parameter is used to specify which input should trigger a live update. In this case, live_inputs=[0] indicates that the output of the first component should trigger a live update for the second component.

Now, when you run the interface, the output of listen_audio will dynamically update the input of create_ticket, allowing you to trigger function2 based on the output of function1 within a single interface.

Comment: This seems like a GPT generated answer and Interface doesn't have attribute  add_component in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import gradio as gr

def listen_audio(input1):
    # Your audio processing code
    return "problem"  # Example output

def function2(output_of_listen_audio_function):
    # Your ticket creation logic
    return "Ticket has been created"

demo = gr.Interface(
    fn=listen_audio,
    inputs=gr.Audio(sources="microphone", type="filepath"),
    outputs="text",
    flagging_options=["Create Ticket"],
    allow_flagging="never",  # Disable default flagging behavior
    on_click=gr.outputs.from_function(function2),
)

demo.launch()
```

Or Use gr.get_state() within function2 to access the output of listen_audio:

```
def function2():
    output_of_listen_audio = gr.get_state()["output"]
    # Use output_of_listen_audio for ticket creation
    return "Ticket has been created"
```